# How to search/filter for log messages by specified https:// endpoints in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I try to filter for log messages by https:// endpoints such as `https://test.com` to find request/response to external systems in Kibana Discover.

When trying to escape the special characters `message: https\:\/\`. I get the following error:

`Discover: Expected "*", "\", "\n", "\r", "\t", [\ \t\r\n] or end of input but ":" found.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you explain why you want to escape the characters? I assume that the message field you want to search on is of type text.

By quoting the search term you should get the desired results:

message:"https://*"

Regards